# Authenticate Google-Cloud-Storage not using JSON file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

I'm using .Net API and authenticate be setting the path to the service account JSON file in the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.
But what I would like to do is to authenticate by specific specifying the credential-properties in the code (just like I do with AWS and their ID and KEY).

Why? In my use case I don't want to have the json file "exposed" laying around, but want the credential-properties specified in a custom XML config-file encrypted.

My application will read the config-file and decrypt the content (the GCS credentials).

Don't care if it's a service-account or user-account, whatever works best for the about setup, if possible?

And ugly solution would be to dynamically create the JSON file, let the API read it and then delete the file.
If so I would like to limit the amount of properties as much as possible, I have the following properties in a downloaded JSON file. Which are mandatory/needed and which are bloat:

```
{
 "type": "xxx",
 "project_id": "xxx",
 "private_key_id": "xxx",
 "private_key": "xxx",
 "client_email": "xxx",
 "client_id": "xxx",
 "auth_uri": "xxx",
 "token_uri": "xxx",
 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xxx",
 "client_x509_cert_url": "xxx"
}
```

Comment: All contents of the JSON file are needed. Each field is used for a different purpose (some for creating the service account tokens, some for refreshing the token, etc.). It is not a good idea to distribute service accounts in any form. You do not describe the services that you need access to, but in your case, OAuth User Credentials is probably the correct ones to use. The answer in the other question you mentioned is NOT a good answer.

Comment: Ups, just found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389384/use-google-application-default-credentials-without-json-file).

Comment: Yes, you're right. But it's not an issue for my use case. I need this solution for better usability, not better security.
But thanks for pointing it out just in case.

Answer (score 1):

To specify the credentials as a variable (JSON string) instead of a file-path:

```
 Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential cred = Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromJson(JSONString);
 var storage = Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient.Create(cred);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is very weird. I seem to not need to use my GC json file to translate text. Idk why I don't need it but that saves me time from encrypting it. It just feels  weird that this is all working  even though I don't have the translate.py file connected to any sort of json file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32056860)